# b-pagination is loading all data on first load (vuejs)

Tags: vue.js

I have below code. It displays all records on the first load. Once I change page number it gets records as expected.

I have 5 records. On first load, I am getting all 5 records instead of 3 records. However, If I click on page 2 I can see record no 4 and 5. If I change back to page no 1, I get 3 records as expected. However, on the first load, I am getting all 5 records. Is there anything missing in this code?

```
<a-row class="my-1" v-if="data.length > 0">
  <a-col v-for="(item, index)  in paginatedItems" :key="index">
      <b-card>
         <div class="title">{{ item.name }}</div>
       </b-card>
    </a-col>
 </a-row>
<a-row>
<b-pagination @change="onPageChanged" :total-rows="totalRows" :per-page="perPage" v-model="currentPage" class="my-0" />
</a-row>


import Paginate from "vuejs-paginate";

export default {
  components: {
    Paginate
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      paginatedItems: [],
      currentPage: 1,
      perPage: 3,
      totalRows: 0,
      id: 0
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.paginate(this.perPage, 1)
  },
  created() {

    if (this.$route.query.id) {
      this.id = this.$route.query.id;
      this.getItems();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onPageChanged(page){
      this.paginate(this.perPage, page - 1)
    },
    onChangeCurrent(current) {
        this.currentPage = current;
    },
    async getItems() {
      this.page = 1;

      let respond = await getting data from axio;
      if (respond){
          this.items = respond
          this.paginate(this.perPage, 1)
          this.paginatedProducts = this.products;
          this.totalRows = this.products.length;
          this.pageCount();
       }
    },
    paginate (page_size, page_number) {
      let itemsToParse = this.products
      this.paginatedProducts = itemsToParse.slice(page_number * page_size, (page_number + 1) * page_size);
    },
    pageCount() {
      let l = this.totalRows,
        s = this.perPage;
      return Math.floor(l / s);
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to explain better which one is your expected output better than explain what is your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `paginatedItems` instead of  `paginatedProducts` that you have used in `paginate()` method, and also, `items`, instead of `products`, since you haven't defined any of these in `data()` of the component. Also, when you call `getItems()` the order of the assignments and method calls is wrong.

```
async getItems() {
  this.page = 1;

  let respond = await getting data from axio;
  if (respond){


      this.items = respond

     // this.paginatedItems = this.items; //no need to have this, you assign then all items 
      this.totalRows = this.items.length;
      this.pageCount();
      this.paginate(this.perPage, 1); //this should be called last
   }
},
```

full code:

```
    <a-row class="my-1" v-if="data.length > 0">
      <a-col v-for="(item, index)  in paginatedItems" :key="index">
          <b-card>
             <div class="title">{{ item.name }}</div>
           </b-card>
        </a-col>
     </a-row>
    <a-row>
    <b-pagination @change="onPageChanged" :total-rows="totalRows" :per-page="perPage" v-model="currentPage" class="my-0" />
    </a-row>


        import Paginate from "vuejs-paginate";

    export default {
        components: {
            Paginate
        },
        data() {
            return {
                items: [],
                paginatedItems: [],
                currentPage: 1,
                perPage: 3,
                totalRows: 0,
                id: 0
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.paginate(this.perPage, 1)
        },
        created() {

            if (this.$route.query.id) {
                this.id = this.$route.query.id;
                this.getItems();
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onPageChanged(page){
                this.paginate(this.perPage, page - 1)
            },
            onChangeCurrent(current) {
                this.currentPage = current;
            },
            async getItems() {
                this.page = 1;

                let respond = await getting data from axio;
                if (respond){


                    this.items = respond

// this.paginatedItems = this.items; //no need to have this, you assign then all items
                    this.totalRows = this.items.length;
                    this.pageCount();
                    this.paginate(this.perPage, 1); //this should be called last
                }
            },
            paginate (page_size, page_number) {
                let itemsToParse = this.items
                this.paginatedItems = itemsToParse.slice((page_number -1) * page_size, page_number * page_size);
            },
            pageCount() {
                let l = this.totalRows,
                    s = this.perPage;
                return Math.floor(l / s);
            }
        },
    }
```

But it might be better to use `paginatedItems` as computed property and remove on `onPageChanged` method for the event:

```
    export default {
    components: {
        Paginate
    },
    data() {
        return {
            items: [],
            currentPage: 1,
            perPage: 3,
            id: 0
        }
    },
    mounted(){

    },
    created() {

        if (this.$route.query.id) {
            this.id = this.$route.query.id;
            this.getItems();
        }
    },
    computed: {
        paginatedItems(){
            return this.items.slice((this.currentPage - 1) * this.perPage, this.currentPage * this.perPage);
        },
        totalRows(){
            return  this.items.length;
        },
        pageCount() {
            let l = this.totalRows,
                s = this.perPage;
            return Math.floor(l / s);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onChangeCurrent(current) {
            this.currentPage = current;
        },
        async getItems() {
            this.page = 1;

            let respond = await getting data from axio;
            if (respond){
                this.items = respond

            }
        },


    },
}
```

**Edit:** there is issue also with the slice, since you would always initially skip first three items, so instead of:

```
this.paginatedProducts = itemsToParse.slice(page_number * page_size, (page_number + 1) * page_size);
```

should be:

```
this.paginatedProducts = itemsToParse.slice((page_number - 1) * page_size, page_number * page_size);
```

Comment: @hebeva5592, I have fixed the typos, swapped other products and paginatedProducts, so it should be working now. Also, I have suggested a solution with a computed property, that might be working better and be a better approach in terms of  reactivity

Comment: It's still same. I have changed it to Items.

Comment: @hebeva5592, why do you import vuejs-paginate but use b-pagination instead?

Comment: also, did you try the other approach?

Comment: yes i did. It works on page change. My issue is on the first load. It displays all records on first load.

Comment: @hebeva5592, I think that issue is also in `getItems` the order of the properties' values assignments and the method calls. Please check out the latest edits I made.

Comment: @niklah it looks better now. But I am getting data from second page on first load with pase 1 selected instead of page 1 data.

Comment: @hebeva5592, there is also issue with the way of vars being used in the slice, see my edit at the bottom. Your initial slice should start from .slice(0,3). extracting this way first three items.